# How to create a new column from a constant value in a DateFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
s = Service(executable_path=r'D:\Python3104\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
url = '''http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/Chinese/Reports/CORunning.aspx? 
Date=20220701&RaceNo=2'''
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

#Got the RaceNo from URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
RACENo = ((driver.current_url.split("RaceNo=")[1]))

#Change the RaceNO into Series
RACENo = pd.Series(RACENo)

#Get a DataFrame From HTML 
df = pd.read_html(
str(soup.find("table", class_="table_bd f_fs13")))

#Add a column to DataFrame using RACEno
df = df[:,"RaceNo": RACENo]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2sfv.png)

But it told me: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
Can anyone tell me What i did wrong?

Comment: Why did you think `df[:,"RaceNo": RACENo]` would be valid? Have you read an pandas tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

The following code below should work. You just need to assign the `RACENo` as `str` (not `pandas.Series`) to the new column. I.e. there is no need to convert `RACENo` to a `pandas.Series`.

There are some ways to do it:

1. `df['RaceNo'] = RACENo` - Insert/replace a column with the given value to all rows;
2. `df = df.assign(RaceNo=RACENo)` - [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas.DataFrame.assign) a new column to the DataFrame
3. `df.insert(0, 'RaceNo', RACENo)` - Insert a column at a specified position
4. `df.loc[:, 'RaceNo'] = RACENo` - Create a new column and assign the new value

```py
import time
from numpy import NaN
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = Service(executable_path=r'D:\Python3104\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
url = '''http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/Chinese/Reports/CORunning.aspx?
Date=20220701&RaceNo=2'''
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

#Got the RaceNo from URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
RACENo = ((driver.current_url.split("RaceNo=")[1]))

#Get a DataFrame From HTML
df = pd.read_html(
str(soup.find("table", class_="table_bd f_fs13")))[0]

#Add a column to DataFrame using RACEno
df['RaceNo'] = RACENo
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new column to the existing dataframe you need to assign the values of your Series in that way:

`df['RaceNo'] = RACENo.values`